# Force Xamarin Mono Android to install runtime to external storage

Tags: android, mono, external, sd-card, xamarin

I'm testing an app built with `Mono for Android` on an older Android device (HTC Desire, currently with Android 2.3). The first time, the app is run. It installs 3 packages:

```
Shared runtime, Mono Android-16 and Mono Android-8 support.
```

[Here](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/mono_for_android_1/mono_for_android_1.0), They say they force it to internal storage on purpose. But on my device the shared runtime takes about 40MB of space and quickly leads to low memory condition, so that the app itself can't get installed at all.

Is there a way to force the shared Runtimes to install to `SD`. I can move them manually, yes, but is there a setting in Mono itself?